# Cookies Not Supported for plugin

Tags: cookies, adobe-analytics

I try to test the plugin `getDaysSinceLastVisit` with a simple example like this:

```
document.cookie="visit=visitor; expires=Thu, 29 May 2016 10:00:00 UTC"
                s.prop35=s.getDaysSinceLastVisit(visit);
```

I have enabled the cookies in my browser however I receive the following:

```
Cookies Not Supported
```

What can I do to take the right result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've implemented the Adobe Analytics plugin correctly. Please check the following:

1. You have added the getDaysSinceLastVisit plugin code to the s_code or app measurement file. This is usually done after the config vars are set and AFTER the call to do_plugins.

Example:

```
s.doPlugins=s_doPlugins

/************************** PLUGINS SECTION *************************/

/* Insert getDaysSinceLastVisit Plugin here  */
```

2. You are correctly calling the plugin WITHIN do_plugins and setting a cookie name as a required value.

Example:

```
s.usePlugins=true
function s_doPlugins(s) {  
// Set Plugins Below

// Set Get Days Since Last Visit 
s.prop1=s.getDaysSinceLastVisit('s_dslv');  

};
s.doPlugins=s_doPlugins
/************************** PLUGINS SECTION *************************/

/* Insert getDaysSinceLastVisit Plugin here  */
```

Note that the plugin will automatically create a first party cookie using a s.c_w function. There is no need to use JS to create a cookie or set an expiration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was populating my eVar with 'cookies not supported'. Once I wrapped my variable in single quotes I got it to fire for me.

```
s.eVar1=s.getDaysSinceLastVisit('s_lv');
```

I hope this helps.